# Http Request with adding sql query android

Tags: android, httprequest

I want HTTP request from below link in android. I have tried various ways to add my sql query to my URL but I can't make it happen.

I think the problem is with '*' (star) in the URL.

```
<https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys>?


HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in (\"MSFT\")&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);

        String responseString = out.toString();
        out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //..more logic
    } else{
        //Closes the connection.
        try {
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();

        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in
>   query at index 50: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select
>   * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("MSFT")&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
>               at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:730)

Answer (score 0):

Change the asterisk to "%2A". The asterisk character is reserved for special uses in URLs.

"...select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo....."

Comment: When trying <https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys>? getting error like `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: code sample `handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"));
                    Log.e("response",""+response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });`

Comment: plz try it your self and if you got the response Then send me sample code.Thanxx for replay.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at URLEncoder.encode: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: I already try this <https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys> this is also not working for me try your self and if you get response then just give sample. Thanxxx for replay

Comment: above link is not working Url like this<https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys%3E>?

Comment: <https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22MSFT%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys%3E>? also try this one. plz try it your self and if you got response then send me sample code.Thanxxx